# How to make sender JID (From) anonymous in ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I have certain users and they can chat anonymously. They are having one to one chat. Suppose I want to encrypt the username of sender. How can I achieve this.

What I have done so far :

```
start(_Host, _Opts) ->
   ejabberd_hooks:add(filter_packet, global, ?MODULE, on_filter_packet, 0).

on_filter_packet({From, To, XML} = Packet) ->
        ?INFO_MSG("Packet From intercepted ~p", [From] ),
        Packet.
```

In this code it is returning Packet and I can change the packet in that function.

How can I change `From`, So that it is reflected on client side.

This is `From` in logs:

```
{jid,<<"username">>,<<"domain.com">>,<<"1960117812133817321731161">>,<<"username">>,<<"domain.com">>,<<"1960117812133817321731161">>}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your implementation has a major issue. You are attempting to transform all packets, not only `message` packets. The way you did it, you were going to break the routing by rewrite `iq` and `presence` packet as well

Here is a working module that basically replace the from of the message. I used hash to "encode" the from and make the username "permanent" so that all messages from the same person will appears in a single conversation. However, feel free to replace with the algorithm of your choice:

```
%% To add in ejabberd modules configuration section:
%%   mod_replace_from: {}
-module(mod_replace_from).

-behaviour(gen_mod).

-export([start/2, stop/1]).
-export([on_filter_packet/1]).
-include("jlib.hrl").
-include("logger.hrl").

start(_Host, _Opts) ->
    ejabberd_hooks:add(filter_packet, ?MODULE, on_filter_packet, 50),
    ok.

stop(_Host) ->
    ejabberd_hooks:delete(filter_packet, ?MODULE, on_filter_packet, 50),
    ok.

on_filter_packet({From, To, #xmlel{name = <<"message">>} = XML}) ->
    ?INFO_MSG("Packet From intercepted ~p ~p", [From, XML]),
    NewFrom = replace_jid_user(From),
    {NewFrom, To, XML};
on_filter_packet(Packet) ->
    Packet.

replace_jid_user(JID) ->
    {U, S, R} = split_jid(JID),
    Hash = integer_to_binary(erlang:phash2(U)),
    jlib:make_jid(Hash,S,R).

%% Will be added to jlib.erl
%% This is the reverse of make_jid/3
-spec split_jid(jid()) -> {binary(), binary(), binary()} | error.                              
split_jid(#jid{user = U, server = S, resource = R}) ->
    {U, S, R};
split_jid(_) ->
    error.
```

This is a basic implementation because, while it replies to the question, it is far from a complete solution for anonymous chatting. For example, you will need to handle algorithm to somewhat implement a routing of the packet to allow people to reply and make sure that the packet will reach the original anonymous sender.  I am sure will will face more challenges down the road.

However, this addresses the question and illustrates `From` JID manipulation in ejabberd.